# Why does my program give a "segmentation fault" (core dumped) error after running

Tags: c++, qt, g++, semaphore

I've to create a prime checker using semaphores. The code executes till the "Finding Primes from" part and after that crashes saying "Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)". After searching about this I understand that it happens when the program tries to access a part of memory that isn't available; but I don't understand it in my code. Please do a take a look and thank you!

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QSemaphore>
#include <QMutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#define TOTALSPACE 50

vector<int> buffer(TOTALSPACE);
QSemaphore space(TOTALSPACE), avail;
QMutex l;

int prime_from, prime_to, num_threads;
int total = 0, cnumber = 0;
int in = 0, out = 0;
bool b = false;

//-----Generator------
class Generator : public QThread
{
private:
    int strt;
    int end;

public:
    Generator(int a, int b)
    {
        strt = a;
        end = b;

        cnumber = strt;
    }

    void run()
    {
        while (cnumber < end)
        {
            space.acquire();
            cnumber++;
            buffer[in] = cnumber;
            in = (in + 1) % TOTALSPACE;
            avail.release();
        }

        b = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
        {
            space.acquire();
            buffer[in] = -1;
            in = (in + 1) % TOTALSPACE;
            avail.release();
        }
    }
};

//-----------Checker----------
class Checker : public QThread
{
private:
    int number;

public:
    Checker() {}
    void run();
};

void Checker::run()
{
    while (1)
    {
        avail.acquire();
        l.lock();
        number = buffer[out];

        if (number == -1)
        {
            l.unlock();
            break;
        }

        bool isPrime = false;

        for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(number); i++)
        {
            if (number%i == 0)
            {
                isPrime = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        out = (out + 1) % TOTALSPACE;

        if (isPrime == false)
        {
            total++;
        }

        l.unlock();
        space.release();
    }
}

//-------------Main---------
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    num_threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    prime_from = atoi(argv[2]);
    prime_to = atoi(argv[3]);
    cout << " Number of Threads = " << num_threads << endl;
    cout << " Primes checking from " << prime_from << " to " << prime_to << endl;

    Generator gen(prime_from, prime_to);
    gen.start();
    Checker* thr[num_threads];

    for (int i = 1; i < num_threads; i++)
    {
        thr[i] = new Checker();
        thr[i]->start();
    }

    gen.wait();

    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++)
    {
        thr[i]->wait();
    }

    cout << "Total Primes: " << total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read as-is: can you remove the every-other-blank-line and indent it properly please? I also can't find any code marked "finding primes from".

Comment: I'm running this on the terminal so I wasn't able to indent. Sorry for not noticing that! Just breaking my head over this.

Comment: @LoXatoR `for (int i = 1;` and `for (int i = 0;` ? You probably meant to start both from 0. If you would have used a debugger you would have seen that `thr[0]->wait();` causes the issue, you would have seen that `thr[0]` has a bogus value and you would have asked yourself, "didn't I initialize that?" then you would have looked up the initialization code and seen that you did in fact not initialize `thr[0]`

Comment: It should also be noted that `Checker* thr[num_threads];` is not standard C++ at this time, because `num_threads` is not a constant. Some compilers like GCC provide an extension to allow Variable Length Arrays but it is not standard compliant as of C++14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of things that could cause this. For one, you never check whether there's enough parameters supplied or not (`argc>3`). So you could pass invalid pointers to `atoi`

But far more likely is that you did not initialize `thr[0]` because you start your initialization loop with `for (int i = 1;` but you access `thr[0]` in the loop for synchronization because you start it with `or (int i = 0;`.

In addition it is noteworthy that you are using Variable Length Arrays when you do `Checker* thr[num_threads];` because `num_threads` is not a compile-time constant. That feature is not part of the C++ standard at this time (not in C++14). So, if you want to make your program portable you can do `Checker** thr = new Checker*[num_threads];` and `delete [] thr;` at the end if you want to be diligent (and not use smart pointers).